# Javascript to get system double click interval?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, double-click

Can I use Javascript to get the system's double click interval?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way in JavaScript to retrieve that type of system information.

You might be able to figure out some strange clicking test using onclick and onddblclick to get it, but I doubt it will be exact and would require user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

Using pure JavaScript, and not asking the user to help you? No